# Does mysql_stmt_store_result return only one record at a time

Tags: mysql, c

MySQl 5.6 under Win7, C API prepared statements.  First time using *mysql_stmt_store_result()*.

I prepare a buffer to hold 40 records (e.g., `struct TICK ticks[40]`).  In the bind array, I set the addresses of the elements of the the first struct in the buffer (e.g., `bind.buffer = (char*)&ticks[0].elem1;` etc).  In `bind.buffer_length` I put in the space available in the buffer for all elements of the struct, e.g., `sizeof (ticks.elem1)*40`.  I set some of the other elements of the bind struct, too.

I call *mysql_stmt_store_result()*, then I call *mysql_stmt_fetch()*.  The call to *mysql_stmt_fetch()* gets the first record of the result set and correctly puts it in ticks[0], but that's all it retrieves.  The next call of *mysql_stmt_fetch()* retrieves the second record and overlays that on the first, at ticks[0], and subsequent calls do the same.

I was following the example on the mysql_stmt_fetch() page in the mysql ref manual, [mysql-stmt-fetch](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-stmt-fetch.html).  I tried setting up a cursor to no avail.  Is it so that *mysql_stmt_store_result* only effects that the result is buffered on the client, but that it relies on mysql_stmt_fetch and so retrieves but one record at a time?  The documentation implies it retrieves a "complete result set", (see [the mysql page, first paragraph](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-stmt-store-result.html))  Can you suggest what I should do to properly get the full result set buffered on the client side in one call?  Am I misunderstanding the doc -- only one record at a time of a complete result set?  TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `mysql_stmt_store_result()` stores the whole result internally. This is necessary if you intend to use functions such as `mysql_stmt_row_seek()` or `mysql_stmt_row_tell()`. Also, the mysql lib can't tell the number of rows in a result set until after all rows have been fetched. If you store the result, you can get the number of rows in the result set before actually fetching any rows.

Why? For statements with a large result set, executing the statement may not necessarily retrieve all rows. Think of querying a database over a network connection. If you'd get the whole result set with the first fetch, the first fetch (or the query itself) may take a very long time to process for large result sets, while consecutive fetches would be fast. Since in most cases you don't need all data with the first fetch, mysql will only request the first few rows. If you actually read them using `mysql_stmt_fetch()`, the mysql lib will request further rows until there are no more rows to fetch.

The call to `mysql_stmt_store_result()` will fetch all rows at once.

Pros:

- you can arbitrarily position the row cursor
- you can get the total number of rows in advance

Cons:

- you can't tell in advance how much memory you'll need to store the complete result set
- you can't tell in advance how much time you'll need to retrieve the complete result set

Comment: Your explanation makes good sense to me, but it seems to be in contradiction with a paragraph on the msql_stmt_fetch page [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-stmt-fetch.html), _"By default, result sets are fetched unbuffered a row at a time from the server. To buffer the entire result set on the client, call mysql_stmt_store_result() after binding the data buffers and before calling mysql_stmt_fetch()."_  According to this, it seems I should be able to get the complete result set on the machine that initiates the call.  Maybe they mean 'server', not 'client'.

Comment: Your quote essentially summarizes what I was trying to say. Use ``mysql_stmt_store_result()`` to fetch the entire result set, buffering it on the client side.